# Magento, add configurable product to cart

Tags: php, magento

Can't find  topic related information, probably I am just asking wrong question.

For example I have configurable product, a T-Shirt.

I need to add some text on top of this T-Shirt, select size, colour, etc. Also I need to apply transformations to this text like distortion, rotation, etc.

Then I have to save this product in to the cart using my custom module. Also printer operator should be able to see all those parameters before printing t-shirt order.

What type of Magento product do I use? How do I add those products to cart? 
I need any related documentation and/or articles. Not source code :)

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is not enough but you can try using product "Custom Options".
Check this documentation from magentoGo for custom options:
http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/create-custom-variants-and-options-of-a-product/